# Help with Joomla site accumulating massive cache in com_content

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

Not sure what the exact problem is,
but the com_content cache get accumulated real quickly and the site is crashing when browsing from homepage to any category.
Urgent assistance needed.
It might be something simple, an experienced joomla developer would know.

Comment: Did you edit some core files of joomla? Do you use plugins?

Comment: I didn't edit any files..Some plugins I had used. Will the plugins usage will cause this?

Comment: Maybe the usage cause this. It depends on the plugins and their cache usage... PLEASE provide more information or delete your question! How should anybody be able to answer your question without any information? As an example try to answer the question "my computer does not boot"...

Comment: More info needed - is the site under heavy traffic load, are there many many pages within the site, are the files in the /cache/ folder standard joomla cache files or do you have an image gallery or some other add-on that is dumping files into that folder? Are these definitely Joomla files or the result of some sort of hacker activity? How many files and of what size (per file).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't leave us much intel here so based on that.

Why don't you disable the cache in Global Configuration > System > Cache Settings. It's not really a solution but it will most likely fix your problem in the short-term.

Unfortunately the caching is a bit broken in some joomla 1.5.x versions, and their plugins.